# Edit meeting no longer working - Office 365 Graph API

Tags: php, graph, office365api

We have a guest book which uses office 365 calanders to manage passes (1-10) and who has been assigned which pass and when.

We use a tablet running a web page for signing people in and out.

This was working fine up till today.

We are no longer able to sign anyone out using the php api.

I have looked through the api known issues and the new release notes and cannot find anything in there.

I have tried turning on error reporting and am not getting anything back.

```
//update current event
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$curl = curl_init();

$endnow = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
$timestamp = strtotime($endnow);
$time = $timestamp - (1 * 60 * 60);
$endnow = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $time);
$test = "{\r\n\t\"end\": {\r\n\t\t\"dateTime\": \"" . $endnow . ".0000000\",\r\n\t\t\"timeZone\": \"UTC\"\r\n\t}\r\n}";
//echo $test;
$authurl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/guest".$_POST['signoutnumber']."@trustsystems.co.uk/events/";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $authurl.$id,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PATCH",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $test,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $result->access_token,
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Host: graph.microsoft.com",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-length: 86"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

What this code should do, is update the clicked calendars (on previous page) end time to now.

This isnt throwing an error or infact doing anything at all from what I can tell.

This worked last week can anyone shed any light?

Edit:

I have printed the response and this is what I am getting:

`{ "error": { "code": "ErrorPropertyValidationFailure", "message": "At least one property failed validation.", "innerError": { "request-id": "7cc59f12-8523-40d2-bef4-f1b0a09cea59", "date": "2019-10-31T10:11:21" } } }`

also for a period of yesterday afternoon this randomly started working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found what potentially might be my issue.

I was sending over the meeting invite using "GMT Standard Time" and the request to change the meeting end time was in "UTC".

This worked fine up until daylight saving time was applied.

I have changed the time zone and it appears to work, however I will test over the next 24 hours.

**edit:** 
so this actually now works. What I had to do was this for the date time:

```
//what this does is check if we are in daylight savings or not
    if (date('I', time()))
{
    $endnow = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
    $timestamp = strtotime($endnow);
    $time = $timestamp - (1 * 60 * 60);
    $endnow = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $time);
}
else
{
    $endnow = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", time()+3600);
    $timestamp = strtotime($endnow);
    $time = $timestamp - (1 * 60 * 60);
    $endnow = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the $response variable contain?  If there was a problem with the API call then the error message would be in $response.

Edit:

Ok, the error in $response suggests that it doesn't like something in $test.  What does $test contain when this error is generated?

Comment: Hi Ryan, Not sure why I didnt think of this. I have popped the response into the question